# Port dissapears from URI in adb android.intent.action.VIEW command?

Tags: android, android-intent, adb, port, caldav

### Context

While attempting to automatically configure DAVx5 over (usb) adb, I noticed the port that I include in the intent, does not arrive at the DAVx5 app.

### Example

I can run:

```bash
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d caldavs://some_nextcloud_username:some_nextcloud_password@some_long_onion.onion:9001/remote.php/dav/principals/users/some_nextcloud_username
```

Which has output:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=caldavs://some_nextcloud_username:some_nextcloud_password@some_long_onion.onion:9001/remote.php/dav/principals/users/some_nextcloud_username }
Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

However, in the app, that results in:

[image]
As one can see, the `:9001` part is dropped from the url.

### Verification

I verified that the port dropping out is indeed the issue, by manually adding the port into the url that is displayed, and pressing "Login", which yields a succesful login.

### Question

How can I modify the `adb` command to ensure that the port is included in the url with which the DAVx5 tries to login?

### Comment

In response to the comments, I have looked into the source code, and expect I should add something like `.port(uri.port)` after the `.path(uri.path)` line [here](https://github.com/bitfireAT/davx5-ose/blob/6d278b7e04e6583b31bb0da57a82170f0293bee5/app/src/main/java/at/bitfire/davdroid/ui/setup/DefaultLoginCredentialsModel.kt#L97):

```
 intent.data?.normalizeScheme()?.let { uri ->
            // We've got initial login data from the Intent.
            // We can't use uri.buildUpon() because this keeps the user info (it's readable, but not writable).
            val realScheme = when (uri.scheme) {
                "caldav", "carddav" -> "http"
                "caldavs", "carddavs", "davx5" -> "https"
                "http", "https" -> uri.scheme
                else -> null
            }
            if (realScheme != null) {
                val realUri = Uri.Builder()
                    .scheme(realScheme)
                    .authority(uri.host)
                    .path(uri.path)
                    .query(uri.query)
                givenUrl = realUri.build().toString()

                // extract user info
                uri.userInfo?.split(':')?.let { userInfo ->
                    givenUsername = userInfo.getOrNull(0)
                    givenPassword = userInfo.getOrNull(1)
                }
            }
        }
```

I did not yet compile the source code to install the app and inspect whether that would add the port.

Comment: Could be a simple bug. I would check the source code of the activity that handles the VIEW action.

Comment: If you have AndroidSDK installed I would make the change and execute `gradlew assembleDebug` to check if it compiles and then you can check the APK. If everything works as expected you can generate a pull request on the project.